# float division by zero Python

Tags: python, decimal, division

I,m trying to divide a number by other which is tiny. "q" is always a float number between 0 and 1 and when n is over 1000, output says "float division by zero" because it rounds the small number to zero. I have tryed with Decimal but still not working

```
#Librerías
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from decimal import Decimal

#Datos
p = float(input("Introduzca probabilidad de error de bit: "))
while p < 0 or p > 1:
    p = float(input("Introduzca probabilidad de error de bit: "))
n = int(input("Introduzca número de bits: "))
while n < 0:
    n = int(input("Introduzca número de bits: "))

#Cálculos
q = 1-p
pexito = (q**n)
intentos = 1/pexito
print()
print("El número medio de intentos es:",intentos)
print()
print("La probabilidad de transmitir correctamente",n,"bits es:",pexito)



ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-606e023fc7ec> in <module>
     15 q = 1-p
     16 pexito = (q**n)
---> 17 intentos = 1/pexito
     18 print()
     19 print("El número medio de intentos es:",intentos)

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting. If you divide by a really small number, you'll get a very big number, up to a point. With 64 bits, the limits are somewhere around `1e-323` and `1e+308`. Does it really matter if you need `1e300` "attempts" (`intentos`)  or `1e500`? Functionally, the probabilities will be zero at that point, so it might as well take infinite attempts. Just handle `pexito == 0.0` as a special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try increasing [your precision](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/decimal.html):

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 2*n

a = Decimal(a)
b = Decimal(b)
c = a/b
```

Comment: This won't work when `p = Decimal(0.001)` for example, because `p ** n` will need more than `2*n` decimal places to not be zero.

Comment: `2*n` is just an example, guess the author would figure out the general idea.

Comment: Yes, and 0.001 is just an example. However many decimal places you add, you won't necessarily have enough because p could be small enough that `p ** n` is still zero. You would have to make the number of decimal places depend on `1/p`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exact arithmetic with fractions using the [`Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) class from the standard library:

```py
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> n = 2000
>>> p = Fraction(1, 2)
>>> result = p ** n
>>> 1 / result
Fraction(114813069527425452423283320117768198402231770208869520047764273682576626139237031385665948631650626991844596463898746277344711896086305533142593135616665318539129989145312280000688779148240044871428926990063486244781615463646388363947317026040466353970904996558162398808944629605623311649536164221970332681344168908984458505602379484807914058900934776500429002716706625830522008132236281291761267883317206598995396418127021779858404042159853183251540889433902091920554957783589672039160081957216630582755380425583726015528348786419432054508915275783882625175435528800822842770817965453762184851149029376, 1)
```

The `Fraction` constructor also accepts a string in decimal format like `'0.5'` or an exact fraction like `'1/2'`, so you can do `p = Fraction(input(...))` instead of `float(input(...))`.

Note that this will still give you a `ZeroDivisionError` if the result is *actually* zero (which happens when `p` itself is zero).

Answer (score -3):

Try casting pexito as a float on line 17

```
    intentos = 1/float(pexito)
```

Comment: This is just as wrong as it was when someone else posted it 5 minutes earlier.

Answer (score -5):

As `n` is an integer. SO

```
q = 1-p
pexito = (q**n)
```

`pexito = (q**n)` is also an integer. that is why division by zero exception is raised. if you want to make `intentos = 1/pexito` to be a floating-point division then just write it as:

```
intentos = 1/float(pexito)
```

But keep in mind `float` is `64` bits, and `decimal` is `128` bits. **If `n` is a large number then use `double` or `decimal` instead of float.** 
It will solve division by zero issue.

**Updated:**

Here is the correct code:

```
#Librerías
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from decimal import Decimal

#Datos
p = float(input("Introduzca probabilidad de error de bit: "))
while p < 0 or p > 1:
    p = float(input("Introduzca probabilidad de error de bit: "))
n = int(input("Introduzca número de bits: "))
while n < 0:
    n = int(input("Introduzca número de bits: "))

#Cálculos
q = 1-p
pexito = (q**n)
intentos = 1/float(pexito)
print()
print("El número medio de intentos es:",intentos)
print()
print("La probabilidad de transmitir correctamente",n,"bits es:",pexito)
```

Just check it with value 0.5 and 5. It is working perfact! But for large number you have to calculate the number of bit it require and use key word accordingly. thanks

Comment: You can verify that both of these things are wrong by using a REPL - try writing `0.5 ** 5` and you will see it is a float even though 5 is an integer. Then try writing `1 / float(0)` and you will see that it still gives a `ZeroDivisionError`. Please test before you post.

Comment: Let me check it what are the value you enter after running this script?

Comment: So try it with `0.5 ** 2000`.

Comment: There isn't even a `double` type in Python; the `float` type is a double-precision IEEE 754 floating-point number (i.e. `float` is 64 bits, not 32 bits), and Python doesn't have native single-precision floats. I think the problem here is that you are trying to write an answer to a question that you actually don't know the answer to.

Comment: thanks for the correction you were right there is no double in python. Actually python `float` is 64 bit that is equivalent to `double` of C/C++.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208202/discussion-between-umar-hayat-and-kaya3).